# read.table, diff and intersect error

Tags: r, diff, intersect, read.table, write.table

I have written a script to read a file from disk and check the values in it and write 3 other files on disk. Unfortunately, something that seemed to be very straight forward came out being a headache. The code is:

```
Arqcodnegs ="result/lista_de_codnegs.txt"
dirout   = "./result/"
Codnegs_fornecidos = c("ABC", "A1B2", "PETR3")

Verifica_codneg = function (Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs) {

  if (!file.exists(Arqcodnegs)) {
    stop("Falta arquivo lista_de_codnegs.txt")
  }

  Codnegs_lidos = read.table(Arqcodnegs,header=FALSE, sep='\t', quote='\"', stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

  Codnegs_negativos = c(setdiff (Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs))

  Codnegs_positivos = c(intersect (Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs))

  write.table(Codnegs_lidos, paste(dirout, "lista_de_codnegs_lidos.txt", sep=''), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep='\t')

  write.table(Codnegs_negativos, paste(dirout, "lista_de_codnegs_negativos.txt", sep=''), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep='\t')

  write.table(Codnegs_positivos, paste(dirout, "lista_de_codnegs_positivos.txt", sep=''), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep='\t')

}
```

The file "lista_de_codnegs.txt" has the following values in it:

"PDGR3"
"PETR3"
"PETR4"

As expected, the file "lista_de_codnegs_lidos.txt" returns the appropriate values in one single column, meaning "PDGR3", "PETR3" and "PETR4".

But, the main problems are:

1. The file "lista_de_codnegs_negativos.txt" returns "ABC", "A1B2", "PETR3", but the it should have returned "ABC" and "A1B2", only.
2. The file "lista_de_codnegs_positivos.txt" returns no values, but it should have returned "PETR3".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are ocmparing to `Arqcodnegs`, which contains none of the variables from `Codnegs_fornecidos`. So, expected behaviour. What do you really want to compare it to? colnames of codnegs_lidos?

Comment: I want to check if Codnegs_fornecidos can be found in the file Arqcodnegs. The Codnegs_fornecidos found are written in the file Codnegs_positivos, and the ones not found are written in the file Codnegs_negativos.

Comment: You could do `codnegs_negativos=setdiff(codnegs_fornecidos, codnegs_lidos)`, but depends on what your data looks like.

Comment: Yes, I could compare Codnegs_fornecidos with Codnegs_lidos, as you have indicated. However, I prefer to compare with Arqcodnegs because I use Arqcodnegs as a form of control, and check for discrepancies later.

Comment: @Newbie1971 You understand that you're working toward `Arqcodnegs ="result/lista_de_codnegs.txt"`, i.e a character string, and not to the content of the file loaded into your `Codnegs_lidos` variable ? Please confirm me this, if you changed your code, please [edit] your question

Comment: @Tensibai I want to compare Codnegs_fornecidos = c("ABC", "A1B2", "PETR3") with the content of the file Arqcodnegs ="result/lista_de_codnegs.txt" and generate 3 output files.

Comment: If you're working with the contents of a file, you need to read it. Right now, all you have is the address of the file. You did read it, but stored it somewhere else.

Comment: @Heroka I am reading the file by: Codnegs_lidos = read.table(Arqcodnegs,header=FALSE, sep='\t', quote='\"', stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

Comment: Yes you are, but the file contents (which you apparently want to do something) are stored under another variable.

Comment: @Heroka so, what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Newbie compare things to something you actually want to compare them to, and not to the address. So for this example you should probably compare to Codnegs_lidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here, as mentioned by @Heroka Change `Arqcodnegs` to `Codnegs_lidos` 
 and it will function correctly as `Arqcodnegs` is a character string referring to a file path. As such `setdiff()` is looking to find the difference between the character string and the object `Codnegs_fornecidos`

```
  Codnegs_negativos = c(setdiff (Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs))

  Codnegs_positivos = c(intersect (Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs))
```

**EDIT: This code should get what you're after.

```
Arqcodnegs ="result/lista_de_codnegs.txt"
dirout   = "./results/"
dir.create(dirout)
Codnegs_fornecidos = c("ABC", "A1B2", "PETR3")

Verifica_codneg = function (Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs) {


  Codnegs_lidos = read.table(Arqcodnegs,header=FALSE, sep='\t', quote='\"', stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

  Codnegs_negativos = c(setdiff (Codnegs_fornecidos, Codnegs_lidos))

  Codnegs_positivos = c(intersect (Codnegs_fornecidos, Codnegs_lidos))

  write.table(Codnegs_lidos, paste(dirout, "lista_de_codnegs_lidos.txt", sep=''), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep='\t')

  write.table(Codnegs_negativos, paste(dirout, "lista_de_codnegs_negativos.txt", sep=''), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep='\t')

  write.table(Codnegs_positivos, paste(dirout, "lista_de_codnegs_positivos.txt", sep=''), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep='\t')

}

Verifica_codneg(Codnegs_fornecidos = Codnegs_fornecidos, Arqcodnegs = Arqcodnegs)
```

Comment: I have changed as pointed out, and it is not returning the appropriate answer. What I got is: > Codnegs_positivos
character(0)
> Codnegs_negativos
[1] "result/lista_de_codnegs.txt"
>

Comment: The character string, within the context of the question is a destination. I do see where you are coming from and will adjust my wording as technically it is simply a character string, thank you.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger I tried the code you provided above, and it returned: > Codnegs_negativos
[1] "ABC"   "A1B2"  "PETR3"
> Codnegs_positivos
list() The expected answers would be Codnegs_negativos "ABC" "A1B2" and Codneg_positivos "PETR4"

Comment: @Tensibai I am sorry, but I am not understanding your comment above.

Comment: Very strange, as I am getting what you are looking for.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger I ended RStudio, tried a new script with the code you provided and also a new file "lista_de_codnegs.txt", and I am still having the same results as before. No clue why we are getting different results....

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger I have tried everything again, and in a different computer, and the results are still the same: > Codnegs_lidos
     V1
1 PDGR3
2 PETR3
3 PETR4
> Codnegs_negativos
[1] "ABC"   "A1B2"  "PETR3"
> Codnegs_positivos
list()
I dont know what could be wrong.

Comment: Try using just this:
`Arqcodnegs = c("PDGR3", "PETR3" , "PETR4")

Codnegs_fornecidos = c("ABC", "A1B2", "PETR3")

Codnegs_lidos = Arqcodnegs

Codnegs_negativos = c(setdiff (Codnegs_fornecidos, Codnegs_lidos))

Codnegs_positivos = c(intersect (Codnegs_fornecidos, Codnegs_lidos))`

Then work it back to your original intent.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger now it worked! It seems the problem is related with the read.table function. Any clue about how to work this around?> Arqcodnegs
[1] "PDGR3" "PETR3" "PETR4"
> Codnegs_lidos
[1] "PDGR3" "PETR3" "PETR4"
> Codnegs_negativos
[1] "ABC"  "A1B2"
> Codnegs_positivos
[1] "PETR3"

Comment: @Newbie1971 Is your data separated by a tab or a comma? "\t" indicates a tab, if they are not a tab then you would have all the items in a single column and row, resulting in the wrong output. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger By tab.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger I found the solution. Just replace the line Codnegs_lidos = read.table(Arqcodnegs,header=FALSE, sep='\t', quote='\"', stringsAsFactors=TRUE) by Codnegs_lidos = as.matrix(read.table(Arqcodnegs,header=FALSE, sep='\t', quote='\"', stringsAsFactors=TRUE)).